# Discrete metric on an abelian group that arises from a norm on the group

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Recall that for any space $X$, the discrete metric on it is defined by $$d(u,v):=0\ \text{if}\ u=v,$$ $$d(u,v):=1 \ \text{if}\ u\neq v.$$

Now, if $X:=G$ is an abelian group, does the discrete metric on $G$ arise from a norm on $G
$?

My first belief is YES, so for $u,v\in G$, I defined $$\|u-v\|:=d(u,v),$$ and I tried to show that $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm.

(1) $\|u\|=d(u,0)$, so $\|u\|=0\iff d(u,0)=0\iff u=0$.

(2) Triangle inequality is also easy to prove. $$\|u+v\|=d(u,-v).$$

Then, if $u=-v$, $$\|u+v\|=0\leq d(u,0)+d(v,0)=\|u\|+\|v\|.$$

On the other hand, if $u\neq -v$, then $u$ and $v$ cannot be $0$ at the same time, so the while the left hand side is $1$, the right hand side is $2$ or $1$.

**(3)However, I don't know how to show $\|uv\|=\|u\|\|v\|.$** How could I show this? the multiplication is not even equipped in this group.

Or should I instead show $\|au\|=|a|\|u\|$? but then we need to define the norm over a subfield of a vector space.

Have I got mixed up the definition of norm?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by a "norm" on a group?

Comment: @tomasz a norm function defined on a group

Comment: Which is what, exactly?

Comment: @tomasz I don’t know, I think this is what the question asks for... to find a norm on G that can induce discrete metric on it.

Comment: Yes, but what is a norm?

Comment: @tomasz well a function $\|\ \cdot\ \|:G\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that (1) $\|x\|=0$ if and only if $\|x\|=0$; (2)$\|xy\|=\|x\|\|y\|;$ (3) $\|x+y\|\leq \|x\|+\|y\|$

Comment: But you have noted yourself that it does not make sense if $G$ is a group and not a ring. So it is not clear at all what you are looking for.

Comment: @tomasz Ah.. okay, the way to define a norm on an abelian group is different. it replace $(2)$ as $\|mx\|=|m|\|x\|$ for $m\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: This doesn't make sense, either. Such "norm" would be unbounded as soon as the group is nontrivial.

Comment: @tomasz .. then what norm should I search for?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @tomasz trying to find a norm on $G$ that induces the discrete metric.

Comment: @tomasz so could I use the norm defined by $\|x\|:=0$ if $x=0\in G$, and $\|x\|:=1$ for everything else?

Comment: Yes, but this question does not make sense until you decide what you mean by a norm, which you seem to have trouble with...

Comment: @tomasz what should I "mean" by a norm to make this question make sense?.....

Comment: You could just drop your (2), so a norm is simply a submultiplicative function into positive reals which is nonzero apart from the identity. Then yes, what you suggested would work (in fact, it is a special case of the so-called word norm, induced by taking the whole $G$ to be its own generating set). You don't need to assume abelianity.

Comment: @tomasz okay that makes sense.... thanks!

Comment: @tomasz you could post your answer if you want to. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition you seem to be attempting to check does not quite make sense, since $G$ is just a group and not a ring, and not a vector space. Arguably, an abelian group is a module over the integers, and it would make sense to define a norm for it as such, but then it can never be bounded in this case, for a nontrivial group, so it would not give rise to the discrete metric.

What would make sense is to define a norm on a group to be a function into the non-negative reals, which is nonzero apart from the identity, and which is submultiplicative (i.e. $\lvert g_1g_2\rvert\leq \lvert g_1\rvert \lvert g_2\rvert$).

Given the way you induce the metric from a norm (which is the only sensible way, I guess), there is not much of a choice for the norm: you must have $\lVert g\rVert=d(e,g)$, which is $0$ at the identity and $1$ everywhere else if $d$ is the discrete metric. It is easy to check that it is submultiplicative. In fact, it has a name. It is called a [word norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_metric) (where you take the whole $G$ as the generating set).

Note that using this definition, norms on a group correspond exactly to invariant metrics.